# ASP.net MVC - Output from multiple sources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

Is there a better way to display data from multiple sources in MVC via the return View()?

I basically made call to the two disparate sources then filled a common collection where I could combine the results.  Was just wondering if I could return both data objects instead of having to combine them?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks,

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common to use a [ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942822.aspx#id0070047) which can hold multiple collections or other types to pass to your view.

If you don't want / need strongly typed views, you can use ViewBag or ViewData to pass multiple collections to your view as well:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["GratuitousGuid"] = Guid.NewGuid();

    ViewBag.Products = ProductService.GetProducts();
    ViewBag.Countries = CountryService.GetCountries();
    ViewBag.Zombies = ZombieService.GetZombies();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Looks like I have a lot more reading to do.  I appreciate the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple actions to render the different sources as `PartialView`s and then put them together in one overall `View`

Example:

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Foo() {
    return PartialView(repository.GetFoo());
}

public ActionResult Bar() {
    return PartialView(repository.GetBar());
}

public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div id='foo'>
    @Html.Action("Foo")
</div>

<div id='bar'>
    @Html.Action("Bar")
</div>
```

Foo.cshtml and Bar.cshtml would be PartialViews that display each model's data.

**Addendum**

Another reason I like this way is that it lends itself nicely to AJAX updates. For instance, if the Bar section needs to be updated on the page, then you can use jQuery to write:

```
$('#bar').load('/home/bar', function (html) {
    //Set up your returned data here (callbacks and the like)
});
```

without needing to perform a full refresh

Comment: Thanks Andrew I will check it out